# No result from google API PHP

Tags: php, google-maps, curl

I want to get the distance from one point to another using the google API, but I'm having some issues.
My API link is: 
[http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=55.061744,9.429565&destination=Opnæsgård,%20Hørsholm,%20Denmark&alternatives=true&sensor=false](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=55.061744,9.429565&destination=Opn%C3%A6sg%C3%A5rd,%20H%C3%B8rsholm,%20Denmark&alternatives=true&sensor=false)

If I access this link from the browser, I get the correct distance however; when I try to access the exact same URL from my php script, I get an error.

My php script:

```
    <?php
print_r(file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=55.061744,9.429565&destination=Opnæsgård,%20Hørsholm,%20Denmark&alternatives=true&sensor=false'));
?>
```

Output from php script:

```
{ "routes" : [], "status" : "NOT_FOUND" }
```

As you can see, I'm getting two different results with the same URL, and I have no idea why.

I have also tried using CURL in the php script without any luck.

I hope you can help me

//Mikkel

Comment: You need to [urlencode the address](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/#BuildingURLs)

Comment: copied your line of code, and it worked fine unaltered. `"distance" : "text" : "307 km",`,

Comment: use urlencode() to encode the address, then you will get '+' rather than "%20" for spaces.  Although it worked fine just as you have it.

Comment: That is weird since this is currently the only line in the script. I guess the error is on my end then. Thanks for testing